# how to specify constructor in header for child and parent class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, header, parent-child

I am new to C++ and define a parent class in a header file `parent.h`.
It has a constructor `Parent(int a, int b)`.

Now I want to write the header file for the child class `child.h`, which inherits the exact same constructor as the parent class and only has additional member functions.

Do I have to specify the constructor in the child's header file as well? (`Child(int a, int b)`) Or do I only specify the signatures for the additional member functions and specify the constructor in the corresponding `child.cpp`file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructors aren’t inherited. Therefore, if you want your child class to have the specified constructor you will need to provide it explicitly inside your class definition:

```
…
Child(int a, int b) : Parent(a, b) {}
…
```

Or pull in the definition from the parent class:

```
using Parent::Parent;
```

Note that this will pull in *all* constructor overloads. This may not be what you intended.

Comment: Thanks! This means, I specify the signature of the constructor Child(int a, int b) in the header file of the child as well?

Comment: @jesus_is_king Yes, you need to. In fact, the code I wrote goes in the header.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `using Parent::Parent;`?

Comment: @songyuanyao Or something like that yes... :)

Comment: @songyuanyao I intentionally hadn’t added that to keep things simple but now it seems that I must, for completeness.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just tried to point out Someprogrammerdude's ... mistake. :)

Comment: @songyuanyao Absolutely. But it *was* a legitimate omission from my answer :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry to bother again. In my tutorial they always omit the `: Parent(a, b)`. What would be the difference, if I just specify `Child(int a, int b)`in the header file?

Comment: @jesus_is_king Try it! Without that part, your child class would attempt to invoke the parent’s *default* constructor instead of the constructor with two arguments. The tutorial should actually mention that … unfortunately many tutorials aren’t very good. :-(